# Add Text as Italics to Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have an addon that I am working on for Google Docs, and I am trying to insert text as italics. I am trying to insert a Works Cited (MLA Formatting, as seen here[1](http://s3.amazonaws.com/libapps/accounts/581/images/WorksCited.PNG)), and a title needs to be in italics, and the rest of the line needs to be in regular formatting. The methods I've tried either puts the whole document or the entire line in italics, which obviously doesn't work. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Text class has a setItalics() method that can be used to make text italicized.  You will need to break up your larger body of text into smaller parts (one before the title, the title, and one after) to ensure that only the title is in italics.
[Text Class setItalic](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setItalic(Integer,Integer,Boolean))

```
function myFunction() {
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var text = body.editAsText();
var textBeforeItalic = 'I wrote a book called ';
var title = 'Great Book';
var textAfterItalic = ', it is really good.';
text.insertText(0, textBeforeItalic+title+textAfterItalic);
text.setItalic(textBeforeItalic.length,textBeforeItalic.length+title.length,true);
}
```

Comment: How do I break up the text? I think when I jumped into GAS, I just had JavaScript experience and never any training and just learned from what I could on the documentation. I don't think I completely understand the whole body, paragraph, and text differences and functions.

Comment: I updated my initial response to include some sample code, that shows how to do it.

Comment: I see how that works! Thanks a lot for that! I'll plan to use that!

Comment: Actually, I think I may need a different solution. I am trying to input the text at the end of the document. I think the setItalic would have a fit with that, so is there a way to either get the length of the document or some other solution?